# How to pass multiple values in different lines using sendKeys() inside a text box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, sendkeys

I wanted to pass multiple words in different line on to text box, can anyone help me finding out the solution

Expected output :

```
13456,Teena
12378,Tesa
130987,Jhon
```

Comment: Create a common method, pass the parameters as the locator and the value to enter, call that method wherever you need to use sendkeys() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textbox.sendKeys("13456,Teena" + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER + "12378,Tesa" + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER + "130987,Jhon");

Use Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER combination to the sendKeys() method.

Similarly, we can use Keys enum for different non-text keys and pass them to the sendKeys method. The following table has an entry for each of the non-text key present in a keyboard.

Refer - https://artoftesting.com/press-enter-tab-space-arrow-function-keys-in-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: thanks a lot @Uditha Dissanyake it worked!!